# Isn't computing an ANOVA as well CIs bad practice?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, post-hoc

I have read some papers where an ANOVA was performed as part of the analysis methods. Then, when I turned to look at the figures, I find CIs have been computed as well. Moreover, often times these CIs are perfectly symmetrical...that is, likely computed analytically by using something like the t-dist.

However CIs are computed (i.e., parametrically or not), they can still function to perform null hypothesis testing. Thus, the possibility arises for them to contradict the ANOVA.

Isn't this bad practice because it is liable to inflate alpha?

Comment: If they're used to make pairwise comparisons in the case that the ANOVA is not rejected (i.e. where it's argued that differences exist in spite of a lack of rejection of ANOVA), I'd say that's potentially a problem, because it's effectively doing a form of post hoc after non-rejection, and is a second bite at the cherry. But if that isn't being done, it doesn't necessarily constitute a problem (that something *could* be used as a test doesn't mean it is used as a test).

Comment: Also we need CIs to be able to interpret the outcomes.